# Is there any way to have one pod route its traffic through another pod running a vpn client?

Tags: kubernetes, vpn, kubernetes-networking

I have a bare metal Kubernetes cluster and I'd like to run a vpn client in one pod and have my other pods route their connections to the external internet via that pods vpn connection. Is it possible to accomplish this? If so, how?

Comment: Could you give more details about? What did you tried so far? I'm not sure, but *maybe* it works if you connect in the vpn using the node instead of a pod.

Comment: @KoopaKiller I can get the services I want spun up, I just don’t know how to configure the pods to route traffic from one to another, and I was wondering how to do such a thing.

Comment: If you connect on the vpn using the node, maybe this [link](https://docs.projectcalico.org/networking/workloads-outside-cluster) helps.